# resizing tableview cell content view

Tags: ios, uitableview, landscape-portrait

Hello I am new to ios development. I am developing application where I have a pageViewController which contains child viewController A. in A controller I have a tableview.
I am handling rotation change and in landscape mode I make new CGRect for pageViewController. 
the problem is now in landsape mode my tableview is not fit to the bounds of pageViewController and its cell content is out of screen. please give me a hint.

here is my controller code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_channelsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChannelsCell";
    MBChannelsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    MBChannel *selectedChannel = [_channelsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.channelName.text = selectedChannel.name;
    cell.channelNumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %s",indexPath.row + 1, "."];


    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:34.0f/255.0f
                                                          green:91.0f/255.0f blue:172.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }else{
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:41.0f/255.0f
                                                           green:114.0f/255.0f blue:198.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }

    UIButton *favourite = cell.buttonFavourite;
    favourite.tag = indexPath.row;

    [favourite addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(makeFavourite:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *arrow = cell.buttonArrowRight;
    arrow.tag = indexPath.row;

    [arrow addTarget:self
              action:@selector(navigateToProgram :)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you use custom cells in your tableView? Please paste here some code from your table view controller

Comment: sure I use custom cell.above is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Autolayout. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

It will allow you to essentially attach the views to the sides/top/bottom as needed for autorotation.

Comment: using auto layout and constraints I solved the problem. thanks a lot :)